# Cannot edit cells after touching combobox - I think i've encountered a bug

Tags: vba, excel, user-interface, debugging

So here i was building a form in excel for work ya, and to make it easy on the eyes and fool proof i removed 90% of the UI. On that form i put some activex combo boxes. Everything was perfect, and then i tried to edit a cell after i entered in the data in that combo box, but low to my woes i couldnt.

It seemed that touching the combo box locked every other cell in the form. Flabbergasted i did some experimenting and found a way to isolate the issue. Thus i created a test environment for the error(doc linked below). When the UI is removed clicking the combobox locks all other cells. But when the UI is there, no issue happens. Furthermore it seems the formula bar being disabled is the cause.

Is this a bug, a programming error, or something else. I'm at a total lost and would appreciate any help.

[My test File, for those how want to try it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/if3ey3u10wl3qiy/BugTest.xlsm?dl=0)

When in edit mode shift+esc to hide UI, when hidden hold shift+ctrl then type edit to bring back UI.

Comment: FYI people here are *very* unlikely to download and run your code.

Comment: Yeah, i realize that. Dont risk running malicious code. This isnt malicious, but my words mean nothing.

Comment: The cells are not actually locking. I am having the same issue currently after running thru what I thought were some final tests on a finished product. This must be an activex bug, I've already ran into a few others such as the text boxes and font within drastically changing size. For this issue however, it seems simply selecting another worksheet and then returning corrects it.